# Pattern not matching a file path input

Tags: java, regex

I have an issue in my `else` statement. It is displaying **"Pattern Not Found"** for the value matches the `String`. Can someone help me with this?

**Here is the code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        String url = "https://tfs.tpsonline.com/IRIS%204.0%20Collection/_apis/tfvc/items?scopePath=$/IRIS.Base.5.0.1/CI_CD/Install/ReleaseNotes/&recursionLevel=OneLevelPlusNestedEmptyFolders&api-version=2.1";
        String response = getURLResponse(url);
        JSONObject obj_JSONObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
        JSONArray obj_JSONArray = obj_JSONObject.getJSONArray("value");

        for (int i = 0; i < obj_JSONArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj_JSONObject2 = obj_JSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String value = obj_JSONObject2.getString("path");
            String Release_Pattern_Value1 = "5.0.1.78";

            String input = value;
            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("ReleaseNote.*[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]").matcher(input);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                String pattern = matcher.group(0);
                String pattern_value = pattern.split("_")[1];

                if (pattern_value.equals(Release_Pattern_Value1)) {
                    System.out.println(pattern_value);
                    System.out.println("Pattern Match");
                    break;

                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Pattern Not Found");
            }
        }
}
```

JSON value of the *path* key set into `value` variable in the below statement

```
String value = obj_JSONObject2.getString("path");
```

evaluates to *$/IRIS.Base.5.0.1/CI_CD/Install/ReleaseNotes/ReleaseNotes_5.0.1.73.txt*

Comment: Your `else` block is related to the  `if (matcher.find())` block. Fixing your indentation will make things clearer .

Comment: what string _should_ match but does not?

Comment: 5.0.1.78 this match the string but it shows Patern not found  as well as Patern Found @Mick Mnemonic

Comment: Yes if (matcher.find()) not find the string then it should display pattern not found but it is display it for the values that matches too @Arnaud

Comment: Well there's no `ReleaseNote` in there...

Comment: @FahadHaroon how does Release_Pattern_Value1 match the pattern? It doesn't contain `ReleaseNote`. Also, you would need to escape the `.`s that you want to mean a literal dot.

Comment: What values `String value = obj_JSONObject2.getString("path");` evaluate to?

Comment: Please let us know the input value which is getting tested there which you get from the JSONObject

Comment: it display value like this $/IRIS.Base.5.0.1/CI_CD/Install/ReleaseNotes/ReleaseNotes_5.0.1.73.txt @Mick Mnemonic

Comment: So then your question boils down to why `$/IRIS.Base.5.0.1/CI_CD/Install/ReleaseNotes/ReleaseNotes_5.0.1.73.txt` doesn't match pattern `ReleaseNote.*[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]`?

Comment: 5.0.1.96,
5.0.1.100,
5.0.1.101,
5.0.1.4,
5.0.1.59,
5.0.1.60,
5.0.1.61,
5.0.1.62,
5.0.1.63,
5.0.1.64,
5.0.1.65,
5.0.1.66,
5.0.1.67,
5.0.1.68,
5.0.1.69,
5.0.1.70,
5.0.1.71,
5.0.1.72,
5.0.1.73,
5.0.1.74,
5.0.1.75,
5.0.1.76,
 this type of values are comming from JSONObject @Praveen

Comment: yes it should return else statement if value doesnt match but it returning the else statement when string matches too @Mick Mnemonic

Answer (score 0):

You should ignore the **path** and the **extension** before matching with regular expression,

```
String releaseNote=value.substring(value.lastIndexOf("/")+1);//remove the path
releaseNote=releaseNote.substring(0,releaseNote.lastIndexOf('.'));//remove the extension
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^ReleaseNotes_.*[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]$")
         .matcher(releaseNote);//add '^' '$' in start and end to ensure it matches the begining and end of line
```

Comment: Problem is not with my regex it is working fine but the problem is with the else statement it displaying Pattern not found even the pattern is found @Praveen

Comment: With the input you have provided, your regex code does matches but it returns _5.0.1.73.txt_ rather than _5.0.1.73_. I also suggest you to debug for each input you are receiving to identify the root cause of why it is not matching